# Looking for generator of Python <--> XML bindings

Tags: python, xml, data-binding, xsd, xsd2code

I'm looking for a generator which takes schema file(s) (XSD) on input and generates Python code (bindings) able to transform xml file to Python objects and the other way around. It should be customizable so that I could plug in my code dealing with transformation between specific types defined in schema and Python's objects (let's say [`xsd::dateTime`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime) to/from [`datetime.datetime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime)).

Comment: Related: [How to convert XSD to Python Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072853/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.rexx.com/~dkuhlman/generateDS.html

That's the first Google hit.

[How to convert XSD to Python Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072853/convert-xsd-to-python-class)

That's the second Google hit.

Comment: What search term did you use?

Comment: @Piotr Dobrogost: "python xsd" What else could one use?

Answer (score 3):

Try [PyXB](http://pyxb.sourceforge.net/).