# python json response using schema

Tags: python, json, schema

I have an app and a server communicating using json. I'm now trying to "pythonize" my server code as best as I can (I'm a long time C coder and I'm afraid my python code flow looks more C-like than pythonic). 
I have a bunch of messages going back and forth. Thus far the message format was "implicit", and I didn't really define a schema to make it explicit/readable/validatable etc.

Searching through on the topic, I now have a good handle on how to define the incoming message schema, validate it etc. With colander, i might even directly be able to take it into a class.
However, on the outbound side (ie, responses from the server), I want to have a similar well defined structure and interface.

**My question is:**
How do I USE the defined outbound schema while CONSTRUCTING the response data ? A 'C' analogy would be to use a struct.
Essentially, I don't want any place in my code to do something ugly like

```
r = dict(response_field=response_data)
HttpResponse(json.dumps(r))
```

Because them I'm implicitly creating my format on the fly...

I'd rather use the schema as the base to contruct the response

Any thoughts, suggestions, best practices pointers ?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your outbound data contracts with regular Python classes.

Or you might consider [json-schema](http://json-schema.org/) to define the public API interfaces (incoming and outgoing data contracts). You have a [json-schema validator in python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonschema) that can be a good alternative to colander.

If you have structured data à la relational database, then you might consider XSD and XML. [More on this on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072853/how-to-convert-xsd-to-python-class).

If structures and constraints are simple, then [Avro](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.5/gettingstartedpython.html#Defining+a+schema) or [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial?hl=es) might be enough.