# Generate xsd from Python class

Tags: python, xsd

How might I automatically create .xsd files from Python classes?

I am aware that I can automatically create Python classes from .xsd files, but can it be done the other way?

Comment: There is a duplicate available at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072853/how-to-convert-xsd-to-python-class

Hope that solution helps..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use this tool: [generateDS](http://pythonhosted.org/generateDS/)