# Parse an XSD file using python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, data-structures, xsd

I am trying to generate an XML file from a given XML schema. I have been able to do it with pyxb library in python. But the problem is as the XSD gets huge it is impossible to manually encode each and evey tag. Is there any python library which creates a data structure from a given XSD file which can be iterated through

Comment: Can you provide XML schema?

Comment: I can't provide you the original xml schema that i am working on but the xml schema at  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/sample-xsd-file-customers-and-orders1 is more or less of the same structure the only difference being the size. Mine is just bigger

Comment: So you want to generate XML file with random data based on the XSD?

Comment: I want to generate a xml in which some of the fieds will be populated by my UI and rest of the fields can be filled with dummy data. Even if there is a way to generate a XML with random data based on the XSD it will help in solving my purpose upto a large extent.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can generate XML file from XSD file:

```
import requests

with open('file.xsd', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
r = requests.post('https://www.liquid-technologies.com/api/Converter', json={"Filename": "schema.xsd", "Type": "xsd", "Data": data, "TargetType": "xml", "Arguments": {"elementName": "Root", "elementNamespace": "", "addAnyAttributes": False, "addAnyElements": False, "forceOptionItemsToDepthOf": "4", "forceXsiNamespaceDelaration": False, "maxDepthToCreateOptionalItems": "7", "indent": "2", "indentChar": " ", "indentAttributes": False, "seed": "9722"}})
with open('file.xml', 'w') as f:
    f.write(r.json()['Files'][0]['Data'])
```

Comment: Still it wouldn't solve my purpose... I need something explicitly in python which can help me generate xml files

Comment: Can you plz explain me what's happening here and how did you do it?

Comment: On input you have `file.xsd` with XSD schema. On output you get 'file.xml' generated from that XML.

Comment: How were you able to get this API and is there any documentation fori it which I can go through to make it work according to my needs?

Comment: There is no documentation but you can check their [website](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/online-xsd-to-xml-converter) for more information

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! You have made my life a lot easier

Answer (score 10):

This library seems to do what you want: https://pypi.org/project/xmlschema/

After skimming the documentation I have found this code example: https://xmlschema.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#xsd-declarations

```
>>> import xmlschema
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> schema = xmlschema.XMLSchema('xmlschema/tests/test_cases/examples/vehicles/vehicles.xsd')
>>> schema.types
NamespaceView({'vehicleType': XsdComplexType(name='vehicleType')})
>>> pprint(dict(schema.elements))
{'bikes': XsdElement(name='vh:bikes', occurs=[1, 1]),
 'cars': XsdElement(name='vh:cars', occurs=[1, 1]),
 'vehicles': XsdElement(name='vh:vehicles', occurs=[1, 1])}
>>> schema.attributes
NamespaceView({'step': XsdAttribute(name='vh:step')})
```

So it looks like it can be used to create a python data-structure you can iterate through from an XSD file.

Also this question might be relevant: [How to convert XSD to Python Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072853/how-to-convert-xsd-to-python-class)

Comment: I am still not able to figure out what to do with this. I have got a dictionary which contains all the tag names and their restrictions. How to convert this into a xml file is still baffling me

Comment: The xmlschema library supports conversion to python dictionaries, and it's very pleasant.

Answer (score 1):

[xsdata](https://xsdata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) generates [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) from an XML schema. It can also render a dataclass as XML. A dataclass can be instantiated either by providing all the named parameters to the constructor (which can be statically checked using mypy or pylance) or using a dictionary and [dacite](https://github.com/konradhalas/dacite).

As explained in the [FAQ](https://xsdata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-are-all-properties-marked-as-optional) it is better to use Python 3.10 so that required fields become required arguments of the constructor. In order to do that execute `xsdata init-config` and set `kwOnly=true` in `.xsdata.xml`.